# Mysql pivot like functionality in code

Tags: mysql, sql

I am tackling a problem where I have to convert Table 1 to Table 2 using mysql

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

Table 2 structure is only define. How can I go about this? I have tried using union statement but am unable to convert **Has on Monday** to **Monday** as the column value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write your query as this:

```
SELECT student, class, 'Monday' AS weekday
FROM table_1
WHERE has_on_monday='T'
UNION ALL
SELECT student, class, 'Tuesday' AS weekday
FROM table_1
WHERE has_on_tuesday='T'
UNION ALL
....
```

if you want to insert the result to table_2, use a INSERT query:

```
INSERT INTO table_2 (student, class, weekday)
SELECT ...the select query above...
```